# Batch file - scheduled run vs cmd run - correct date

Tags: date, batch-file

I have the following few lines in a batch file:

```
@echo off 
echo Running dump...
"D:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.16\bin\mysqldump" --host="localhost" --user="****" --password="****" database> "D:\wamp\backup\mysql\"back.%date:~0,2%.sql
echo Done!
```

Supposedly, it should create a backup file with today's day as 01, 02, 03, ..., 31, that is,

```
back.01.sql
back.02.sql
back.03.sql
```

When I run it from CMD, it actually creates it as expected, but when it is run from the scheduler it looks like:

```
back.Mo.sql
back.Tu.sql
back.We.sql
```

What date format should I use to ensure it actually created with number of the day of the month?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working with dates and times in Windows batch is a pain.

The most robust solution is to use WMIC to get the local date and time. It returns a value in the following format:

```
YYYYMMDDhhmmss.dddddd-ttt

YYYY   = year
MM     = month
DD     = day
hh     = hour in 24 hour format
mm     = minutes
ss     = seconds
dddddd = fractional seconds
ttt    = time zone (minutes difference from Greenwich Mean Time)
```

So you can use the following to get the current day of the month in a variable
*Edit - corrected starting substring location from 7 to 6*

```
set curDate=
for /f "skip=1" %%x in ('wmic os get localdatetime') do if not defined curDate set curDate=%%x
set day=%curDate:~6,2%
```

The big advantage of this technique is it will work on any Windows machine in the world, regardless of the locale settings.

---

Here is your code with the technique inserted
*Edit - corrected starting substring location from 7 to 6*

```
@echo off
echo Running dump...
set curDate=
for /f "skip=1" %%x in ('wmic os get localdatetime') do if not defined curDate set curDate=%%x
set "day=%curDate:~6,2%"
"D:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.16\bin\mysqldump" --host="localhost" --user="****" --password="****" database> "D:\wamp\backup\mysql\back.%day%.sql"
echo Done!
```

Comment: this sounds as a good idea, but whenever i echo back the value i get `C:\>echo %day%
%curDate:~7,2%` - sorry i'm not really familiar with command language

Comment: i tried to run it from cms before. now i put your code into `bat` file - i run it today it created file named `back.21.sql` - where is 21 coming from?...

Comment: @Elen - Sorry, I had a stupid error. The substring start location was wrong. The code was taking the last digit of the day and the first digit of the hour. When I tested initially I happened to get the correct answer because the day was 11 and the time was in the 11th hour. The code has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Just setup regional settings `dd.MM.yyyy` for the account under which your task is run. (use control panel or registry HKCU\Control Panel\International\sShortDate for Windows XP at least.